# Set [out=up, in=down] as default path segment parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing lots of paths that look like this:

```
\draw (1) to [out=up, in=down] (2) to [out=up, in=down] (3) to [out=up, in=45] (3);
```

Can I set the [out=up, in=down] part as a global default, to avoid me having to specify it for every segment? I'll still need to be able to override these defaults occasionally, as with the in=45 segment in the example above. So I want to be able to write something like this:

```
\setdefaults{out=up, in=down};
\draw (1) to (2) to (3) to [in=45] (4);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative way to do this is to use the `every to` style.  This gets automatically inserted at the beginning of ... wait for it ... every to.  So `to[something]` is actually `to[every to/.try,something]` (the `.try` is a failsafe to ensure that if `every to` isn't defined then no error occurs).  Hence:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33521/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every to/.style={out=up,in=down}]
\draw (1,0) to (2,0) to (3,0) to [in=45] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces exactly the same line as Torbjørn's examples.

The advantage of this method is that it plays nicely with other things in the picture.  The reason that `\tikzset{in=up,out=down}` is safe is that the keys `in` and `out` only make sense for `to`s.  But if you wanted to put something else in every `to` which had meaning elsewhere (nothing springs to mind right now ...) then `every to` is the better way to pass options to just the `to` parts.

Answer (score 6):

You can add it as a parameter for the `tikzpicture`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=up,in=down]
  \draw (1,0) to (2,0) to (3,0) to [in=45] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or use the `\tikzset` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{out=up,in=down}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,0) to (2,0) to (3,0) to [in=45] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn! But I have to accept Andrew's answer unfortunately :(.

Comment: @JamieVicary Not at all, his was (not surprisingly) the better answer.

Comment: Though I have to admit I still can't think of a circumstance where your method wouldn't work.